# write $A^{6}$ as a Linear combination of $I , A , A^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 4 & 7 \\0 & 2 & 9 \\0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

write $A^{6}$ as a Linear combination of $I , A , A^{2}$ or by a Linear combination of $I , A$.

I found the Characteristic polynomial $P_A(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x+1)$ and concluded that the minimal polynomial
$m_A(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x+1)$ . now I am stuck !

Comment: Maybe use Cayley-Hamilton theorem with elevating a proper polynomial at power 6,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use Cayley-Hamilton Theorem to write $A^{3}$ as $aI+bA+cA^{2}$. Keep multiplying by $A$ to see that any power of $A$ is a linear combination of $I,A$ and $A^{2}$. For $A^{6}$ is is not difficult to compute the coefficients.

Comment: I will try this right now .